# Convert float to modbus registers in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, modbus

some help to convert this method to dart code? I need to convert a float to Modbus registers. I have this method of easymodbus class:

```
public static int[] ConvertFloatToRegisters(float floatValue)
    {
        byte[] floatBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(floatValue);
        byte[] highRegisterBytes = 
        {
            floatBytes[2],
            floatBytes[3],
            0,
            0
        };
        byte[] lowRegisterBytes = 
        {
            
            floatBytes[0],
            floatBytes[1],
            0,
            0
        };
        int[] returnValue =
        {
            BitConverter.ToInt32(lowRegisterBytes,0),
            BitConverter.ToInt32(highRegisterBytes,0)
        };
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some test data where we can see the input and expected output?

Comment: 12425.232435 = [6585,49262,17565,16584]

Comment: Not sure I understand your example. `returnValue` will contain two values based on your posted code but your example returns four integers?

Comment: Also, what library does `BitConverter` come from?

Comment: 43554.975f = [8954,18218]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the same as your C# example but in Dart:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  print(convertFloatToRegisters(43554.975)); // [8954, 18218]
}

Int32List convertFloatToRegisters(double floatValue) {
  final floatBytes = ByteData(4)..setFloat32(0, floatValue, Endian.little);

  final highRegisterBytes = ByteData(4)
    ..setUint8(0, floatBytes.getUint8(2))
    ..setUint8(1, floatBytes.getUint8(3));

  final lowRegisterBytes = ByteData(4)
    ..setUint8(0, floatBytes.getUint8(0))
    ..setUint8(1, floatBytes.getUint8(1));

  final returnValue = Int32List(2);
  returnValue[0] = lowRegisterBytes.getInt32(0, Endian.little);
  returnValue[1] = highRegisterBytes.getInt32(0, Endian.little);

  return returnValue;
}
```

Based on what the code does, I think it can be simplified into:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  print(convertFloatToRegisters(43554.975));
}

Int32List convertFloatToRegisters(double floatValue) {
  final floatBytes = ByteData(4)..setFloat32(0, floatValue);

  final returnValue = Int32List(2);
  returnValue[0] = floatBytes.getUint16(2);
  returnValue[1] = floatBytes.getUint16(0);

  return returnValue;
}
```

### Updated for double example posted later

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  print(convertDoubleToRegisters(43554.975)); // [13107, 13107, 17503, 16613]
}

Int32List convertDoubleToRegisters(double doubleValue) {
  final doubleBytes = ByteData(8)..setFloat64(0, doubleValue);

  final returnValue = Int32List(4);
  returnValue[0] = doubleBytes.getUint16(6);
  returnValue[1] = doubleBytes.getUint16(4);
  returnValue[2] = doubleBytes.getUint16(2);
  returnValue[3] = doubleBytes.getUint16(0);

  return returnValue;
}
```